# How to setup CBLite in existing Jmeter scripts

Tags: jmeter, couchbase-lite

I  need to setup CBLite to a Jmeter script. Can anyone describe how to setup CBlite in existing Jmeter ?

Comment: if you can run android from JMeter, try couchbase-lite-android

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What are you trying to test?